# Django include template url

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template problem. 
I have localizated form so, for example, in all italians pages I have the same form and I'm trying to include that instead repeat the same code over and over in the pages.

In

```
/category1/IT/template.html
```

I have to include the

```
/form/it.html
```

If I use

```
{% include "form/it.html" %}
```

the block defined in the it.html is like empty and I see the default [english] form instead the it one.
If I try to write

```
{% include "../../form/it.html" %}
```

django tells me that the template does not exixt..

If I cut the it.html code in the IT/template.html this work.

Can someone help me to figure why the blocks in the included file do not work?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a naming problem. Really there isn't any other reason they wouldn't populate.

Comment: Make sure your file is correctly resolved.. note that include works just like django templates.. it looks through your TEMPLATE_DIRS / TEMPLATE_LOADERS.